# c# emgu display largestcontour

Tags: c#, visual-studio, opencv, emgucv

I am trying to obtain the largest bounding rectangle of a canny image. I think it works but I don't know how to visualize the rectangle. In the end I want to get my topleft and bottom right coordinates of the rectangle but I think that when I am able to import the image to my void that I can also get those values from the image. I am new to this so I am learning by doing, reading and asking. If I just need to look into some theory then please enlighten me! Willing to learn.

When I run this code my console output is:

```
Emgu.CV.Util.VectorOfPoint
```

The code is this:

```
    private void CannyFrame(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_capture != null && _capture.Ptr != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            _capture.Retrieve(imgOriginal, 0);
            CvInvoke.CvtColor(imgOriginal, imgHSV, ColorConversion.Bgr2Hsv); //Convert the captured frame from BGR to HSV
            CvInvoke.InRange(imgHSV, new ScalarArray(new MCvScalar(iLowH, iLowS, iLowV)), new ScalarArray(new MCvScalar(iHighH, iHighS, iHighV)), imgThres);
            CvInvoke.Canny(imgThres, imgCanny, 100, 200, 3);
            Form1.FindLargestContour(imgCanny, imgContour);
            pictureBox3.Image = imgContour.Bitmap;
        }
    }

    public static VectorOfPoint FindLargestContour(IInputOutputArray imgCanny, IInputOutputArray imgContour)
    {
        int largest_contour_index = 0;
        double largest_area = 0;
        VectorOfPoint largestContour;
        using (Mat hierachy = new Mat())
        using (VectorOfVectorOfPoint contours = new VectorOfVectorOfPoint())
        {
            IOutputArray hierarchy;
            CvInvoke.FindContours(imgCanny, contours, hierachy, RetrType.Tree, ChainApproxMethod.ChainApproxSimple);
            for (int i = 0; i < contours.Size; i++)
            {
                MCvScalar color = new MCvScalar(0, 0, 255);
                double a = CvInvoke.ContourArea(contours[i], false);  //  Find the area of contour
                if (a > largest_area)
                {
                    largest_area = a;
                    largest_contour_index = i;                //Store the index of largest contour
                }
                CvInvoke.DrawContours(imgContour, contours, largest_contour_index, new MCvScalar(255, 0, 0));
            }
            CvInvoke.DrawContours(imgContour, contours, largest_contour_index, new MCvScalar(0, 0, 255), 3, LineType.EightConnected, hierachy);
            largestContour = new VectorOfPoint(contours[largest_contour_index].ToArray());
        }
        Console.WriteLine(largestContour);
        return largestContour;
    }
```

Comment: youmay want to try adding .toString()

Answer (score 0):

I have worked around my problem by making

```
public static VectorOfPoint FindLargestContour(IInputOutputArray imgCanny, IInputOutputArray imgContour)
```

in to

```
private static void FindLargestContour(IInputOutputArray imgCanny, IInputOutputArray imgContour)
```

In the void I deleted

```
return largestContour;
```

Not sure if it is the way to go but I got a little further with my code this way.